# react-native-fbsdk FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKShareKit not found

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, filenotfoundexception, react-native-fbsdk

I have installed the facebook SDK properly. (This is different from the other not found error because it is specifically for react-native-fbsdk and none of the solutions worked.)

I have tested that I have the SDK installed by importing both the `FBSDKCoreKit` header and `FBSDKShareKit` header into `AppDelegate.m` and it compiled and ran with no issue.

However when I installed react-native-fbsdk and linked it and compiled, I get the error of 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' not found. similarly with `FBSDKShareKit`.

The troubleshooting on the github page gives 3 options to check when this occurs:

1. Make sure that the Facebook SDK frameworks are installed in ~/Documents/FacebookSDK.
2. Make sure that `FBSDK[Core, Login, Share]Kit.framework` show up in the Link Binary with Libraries section of your build target's Build Phases.
3. Make sure that ~/Documents/FacebookSDK is in the Framework Search Path of your build target's Build Settings.

Which I have checked and verified that I had all of these there was no solution found. The strange thing is that I can import them in `AppDelegate.m` and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you have the SDK frameworks saved under the folder **~/Documents/FacebookSDK**

Because react-native-fbsdk iOS project have the value "~/Documents/FacebookSDK" hardcoded in its own definition of Framework Search Paths

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me and don't want to do what Facebook tells you (or you don't want to put random stuff on your Documents folder):

1. Replace every instance of `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` in the QuickStart tutorial with the place you do want to store the SDK, in my case `~/Library/FacebookSDK`. That means, unzip the downloaded SDK there and add that route to your project's `Framework Search Paths`. *
2. In Xcode's file tree, expand the `Libraries` group and click on `RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj`. On that project click `Build Settings` and add your route to its `Framework Search Paths`.

And that's it. **Just remember you did this when you update the node module, 'cause this change won't be versioned on your project.**

***Note:** If there are other people working on the project, do not remove `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` from **your** project's `Framework Search Paths`. This is to be consistent with the module installation and the rest of the team can easily `npm install` and use the installation guide as documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Drag & drop in Xcode the FacebookSDK files, for example try with `FBSDKCoreKit.h`

Comment: I added the entire folder to my application group. The error still occurs

Comment: Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNfrBdyEvmY maybe this can help you

Comment: My code worked and compiled. I did the steps exactly as he did (not the login part but all the setup). Where it is failing is in react-native-fbsdk more specifically in the file libraries/RTCFBSDK.xcodeproj/RCTFBSDK/core/RCTFBSDKGraphRequestManager.h where it is failing to import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

Comment: Do you have selected Copy if needed in Xcode? I don't know, maybe you can try with cocoapods. With the video I don't have problems, I inspired too in F8App by Facebook.

Comment: @sookool99 Look this:  https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#33-troubleshooting (Point 2)